# Is there a way for me to randomly generate Strings from an array without duplicating one more than twice?

Tags: java, arrays, math, random, duplicates

currently making a program that will generate a list of Strings from two different arrays, but right now all it does is repeatedly generate Strings the desired amount of times, sometimes with multiple duplicates.

```
    public class ListGenerator
    {
          public static void main(String[] args)
          { 
           //number generator to determine which string to print
           Random generator = new Random();
           int rand;

           //counter to determine number of printed lines
           int counter = 0;

           //coin flip to say which array the string will come from
           Random coinFlip = new Random();
           int coin;

           String[] list1;
           list1 = new String[5]
           list1[0] = "Alpha"
           list1[1] = "Beta"
           list1[2] = "Charlie"
           list1[3] = "Delta"
           list1[4] = "Echo"

           String[] list2;
           list2 = new String[5]
           list2[0] = "Apple"
           list2[1] = "Pear"
           list2[2] = "Grape"
           list2[3] = "Banana"
           list2[4] = "Orange"

           for(counter = 0; counter < 15; counter++)
           {
                coin = coinFlip.nextInt(2)+1;

                if(coin == 1)
                {
                      rand = generator.nextInt(list1.length);
                      System.out.println(list1[rand]);
                }
                else if(coin == 2)
                {
                      rand = generator.nextInt(list2.length);
                      System.out.println(list2[rand]);
                }
           }
           }
    }
```

Is there a way to make it so that I could generate a String like "Apple" or "Beta" no more than twice in the 15 lines generated?

Ex Desired Output:

```
    (1) Apple [printed first time]
    (2) Charlie [printed first time]
    (3) Pear [printed first time]
    (4) Beta [printed first time]
    (5) Apple [printed second time]
    (6) Echo [printed first time]
    (7) Banana [printed first time]
    (8) Banana [printed second time]
    (9) Echo [printed second time]
    (10) Alpha [printed first time]
    (11) Grape [printed first time]
    (12) Delta [printed first time]
    (13) Beta [printed second time]
    (14) Orange [printed first time]
    (15) Grape [printed second time]
```

Where 5 of those Strings were generated twice but not more than twice, but instead in my code it could generate any of those Strings 3, 4, 5, etc. times.

***I know my code isn't organized the best or the most efficient I just need help on this duplication thing***

Comment: BTW, you repeat `list2[0]` five times in your initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `ArrayList` of 20 values, with each value from `list1` and `list2` added twice.

Now [`shuffle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) the list and take the first 15 values.

```
String[] list1 = { "Alpha", "Beta", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo" };
String[] list2 = { "Apple", "Pear", "Grape", "Banana", "Orange" };

List<String> allTwice = new ArrayList<>(20);
allTwice.addAll(Arrays.asList(list1));
allTwice.addAll(Arrays.asList(list1));
allTwice.addAll(Arrays.asList(list2));
allTwice.addAll(Arrays.asList(list2));
Collections.shuffle(allTwice);
String[] result = allTwice.subList(0, 15).toArray(new String[15]);

for (String value : result)
    System.out.println(value);
```

*Example Output*

```
Alpha
Charlie
Echo
Apple
Grape
Delta
Apple
Echo
Grape
Banana
Orange
Orange
Pear
Charlie
Beta
```